# Remove list inside a list python

Tags: python, nltk

Im using NLTK library. I have a list called `chunks` and I want to append words to that list, so I'm doing:

```
def np_chunk(tree):
  chunks = []
  for rama in tree:
      if rama.label() == "NP":
         chunks.append(rama.leaves())
  print(chunks)
```

But this is what I`m getting:
`[['himself']]`
This is a list inside a list. How can I merge them and make it only one list? I want to prevent `rama.leaves()` from returning a list, o directlye removing the inner list from `chunks`
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list.extend` to add all the elements returned by `rama.leaves()` to `chunks`:

```
def np_chunk(tree):
  chunks = []
  for rama in tree:
      if rama.label() == "NP":
         chunks.extend(rama.leaves())
  print(chunks)
```

You can also use `list` addition:

```
chunks += rama.leaves()
```